# How do I store a Web Api auth token in a WPF app?

Tags: wpf, asp.net-web-api, oauth, authorization, restsharp

I have a WPF client of a Web Api that issues a token on authentication. I have no database on the client, and don't know how to store that token. It should be stored securely, but where and how. Memory and disk are pretty insecure without encryption.

At last resort, I could store it in a `SecureString` in the main window viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it indeed turned out best to store it as a `SecureString` in the `ApiClient` class, as close as possible as to where it's needed. I may even only decode it into part of the request, in a custom `RestRequest`, only when the request is executed, which would then mean it would only be vulnerable in the Authorization Provider for the API, which is probably pretty tight.